# SQL Rounding to 2 decimals places Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

I have a problem with the SQL output. Some of the outputs after rounding obtain the correct value, but some output with the same value after rounding off are getting an incorrect value. Is there anyone facing this kind of problem?

Here's my SQL

```
select Line, amount, round(amount,2) amount2 from xxx
```

And this is the output, you can see that the amount is same for `Line` 1 and 2 but the round value is different.

```
Line    amount    amount2
1        6.525       6.52
2        6.525       6.53
3        6.525       6.52
4        2.175       2.18
5       41.325      41.33
6        6.525       6.52
7        2.175       2.17
8       19.575      19.58
9        6.525       6.53
10       2.175       2.18
11      41.325      41.33
12       2.175       2.17
13       2.175       2.18
14       2.175       2.18
15       2.175       2.17
16      36.975      36.97
17       6.525       6.53
18       6.525       6.53
19      19.575      19.58
20       6.525       6.52
21      36.975      36.98
22       2.175       2.18
23       2.175       2.18
24      19.575      19.57
25       2.175       2.18
26       2.175       2.18
27       2.175       2.17
28       2.175       2.17
29       2.175       2.18
30      41.325      41.32
31       2.175       2.18
```

Comment: what is the datatype of amount column

Comment: It's because of the way SQL stores float values

Comment: the datatype is double @fa06

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if your decimal-like values are in fact floats. Here is a repro:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (line INT, amount FLOAT);
INSERT INTO @test VALUES
(1, 6.525),
(2, 6.524999999999999);

SELECT line, amount, FORMAT(amount, 'G17') AS dotnet_g17_formatted, ROUND(amount, 2) AS amount2
FROM @test
```

Result:

```
| line | amount | dotnet_g17_formatted | amount2 |
|------|--------|----------------------|---------|
| 1    | 6.525  | 6.5250000000000004   | 6.53    |
| 2    | 6.525  | 6.5249999999999986   | 6.52    |
```

You can see that float values are stored as an approximation and displayed as such.

The most appropriate solution is to store financial values as `DECIMAL`.

Comment: current datatype is double, meaning I have to cast it to decimal first then round it off?

Comment: Apparently casting to decimal with 3 digits and then rounding to 2 digits seems to work (it should not in my opinion). But yes, give that try.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your error, as my SQL rounds values consistently :) But you can force some consistent behaviour on SQL, try this query (you can choose from three possibilities):

```
select line, amount, 
       round(amount, 2, 1) truncated, --third parameter, if it's other than 0, makes round function to truncate value
       ceiling(amount * 100) / 100 roundUp,
       floor(amount * 100) / 100 roundDown
from @tbl
```

You could write custom rounding using methods to round up and round down I provided.

Comment: the roundup method help with the value i stated, but when it comes to amount with for example 2551.094118 = 2551.1 and single digit will become 15 = 15.01. Rounddown method cant be use because I have amount up to 9 decimal places

Comment: @Apis If you want to round to 2 decimal places, you use `100=10^2`. Generally, if you want to round to `n` decimal places, you have to use `10^n`.

Answer (score 0):

use cast to covert it in decimal then round it

```
select Line, amount, round(cast(amount as decimal(10, 2),2) amount2 from xxx
```

Comment: what does it mean by decimal(10,2). what is parameter 10 do?

Comment: 10 is precision and 2 is scale